# Elastic search to Google big query

Tags: elasticsearch, google-bigquery

How do we send data from elastic search to google big query, Is there any specific connector?
I have been looking into various options and will need data to be available in google big query real time

Answer (score 0):

I found [google_bigquery output pligin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-google_bigquery.html) that might be useful, but I have never use it personally.

> Experiment with the settings depending on how much log data you generate, your needs to see "fresh" data, and how much data you could lose in the event of crash. For instance, if you want to see recent data in BQ quickly, you could configure the plugin to upload data every minute or so (provided you have enough log events to justify that)